# How to add newly added data from firebase to the top of the GridView/ListView and not at the bottom in ANDROID

Tags: android, listview, gridview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app in which I'm retrieving firebase data, but the newly added data shows at the bottom of the list. I want the new data to appear at the top of the list view...

Answer (score 0):

For `ListView` you can use `yourListView.getAdapter().insert(item, 0)`, same will work with `GridView` probably

And don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter, after you finish adding items

Comment: i have set of json data in firebase, just wanted to retrieve them, newest data at first..on android listview when i add new data to the json on firebase..

Comment: @Anil you can't do this. You can only get `N` latest elements using `limitToLast(N)`